# jquery .on(click) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a link on html

```
<a href="#instalacoes" id="instalacoesbutton">Veja aqui »</a></p>
```

and i'm using .on() to do a transition and load content from a external file

```
$(document).on("click", '#instalacoesbutton', function(){
$("#maincontent").slideUp(1000, function () {
$("#maincontent").load("instalacoes.html #instalacoes");
}).delay(500).slideDown(1000);
});
```

any idea why this doesn't work?

if i do:

```
$("#instalacoesbutton").on("click", function(){
$("#maincontent").slideUp(1000, function () {
$("#maincontent").load("instalacoes.html #instalacoes");
}).delay(500).slideDown(1000);
});
```

it works, for the 1st click, but doesn't after the page has been generated dinamically

Comment: Are you adding more than one element w/ the same `id` attribute?  If so, that could be your problem since the `id` attr is required to be unique within the doc

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? Any errors? Console log inside the click function run?

Comment: should be `$(document).ready(function(){$("#instalacoesbutton").on("click", function(){blah...`

Comment: Which server side techonology are you using

Comment: forgot the link, http://clinicavaledodouro.com/

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#instalacoesbutton").on("click", function() {
        $("#maincontent").slideUp(1000, function () {
            $("#maincontent").load("instalacoes.html #instalacoes");
        }).delay(500).slideDown(1000);
    });
});
```

**[Try it yourself on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rs6j/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want the action to fire on all future elements which match that selector, you can set up a click on the document and look for a clicks on that item. This would look something like:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is(".testSelector")) {
        // do stuff to $(e.target)
    }
});
```